# Fur genetics - what are the causes of fur colour decision?

Tags: genetics

This Australian Shepherd puppy's father is a black-tri; mother is a blue merle. What would cause this dog to have so much white color?

[image]

Are there any general explanations as to why this might happen in nature? Other examples of this kind would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One of the reasons can be related to the migration of the neural crest cells that give rise to the pigmented cells. Many genes are involved in this process.